# Filtering posts by post meta data

Tags: query-posts, post-meta

I want to filter posts in such a way that only posts, for which `get_post_meta($post->ID, "project_cat", true)` (it returns a post ID) is equal to my specified value, are shown.

Any way to do this?

I am especially interested in ways to do it compatible with [WP-Paginate plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/wp-paginate/).

Comment: 56% is pretty low - please remember to return to your old questions and accept correct answers. It takes them off the 'unanswered' pile and helps others find solutions more easily. People will also be more willing to offer answers if they know that the OP will respond to them. :)

Comment: See my answer below. It's not clear when/where you want to filter the posts. If you update your answer to include this I can suggest which 'conditionals' you need to check. Alternatively, see the linked query_post example. The general principle is the same - setting the `meta_query` value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `WP_Query` object accepts a post meta argument. Generally speaking you want to do the following:

```
  $my_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'project_cat',
          'value' => 'my-value',
        )
      ),

        // Other query properties
    ) 
  );
```

Where 'my-value' is your 'specified value'.

**Example usage:**

```
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_pre_get_posts' );

  function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // Check this is main query and other conditionals as needed
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 
          'meta_query', 
          array( 
            array(
              'key' => 'project_cat',
              'value' => 'my-value'
            )
          )
        );
    }

  }
```

See [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). All conditionals are available to you. Currently this runs on every main query - which you probably don't want.

Alternatively you can use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_Existing_Query_Parameters) (a simpler, but much less efficient way) to alter the query for only a specific instance in a template.

Comment: @TahirYasin - see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 1):

you can filter the post based on the meta value and display the post on the cms page.

```
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'front_page',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ))
```

please refer the tutorial for step by step explanation

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/filter-posts-custom-fields-wp_query/