# Filter Custom post type by another Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, query

Assume, i have two custom post types - Project and Technology. Every project has a relation to Technology (using ACF). The question is - **How to filter it by Technology**. I tried this approach:

```
'post_type' => 'project',
'meta_query'    => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'technology',
        'value' => $_GET['technology'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'country',
        'value' => $_GET['country'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )
)
```

But it works only for simple relations (like string, int or bool), but i doesn't work with object relations.

Comment: What is the common relation between the two post types? The same post meta?

Comment: i don't understand your question((( i created custom post types with CTP UI, and connected those with ACF.

Comment: How does ACF store relationship? This is probably something you will have to ask ACF support, as it is specific to that plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Get the two post types along with their acf meta and use [PHP Array Functions ( like Array Interset)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to get the common/union or intersection. Additionally [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48516/filtering-posts-by-post-meta-data) will help you in this regards.